# Can i get to know whether record was approved by salesforce login or email

Tags: approval-process

Can i extract approval method like whether record was approved by salesforce login or through email.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this information is stored anywhere. It records who actually processes the step on the [ProcessInstanceHistory](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_objects_processinstancehistory.htm) object. As you can see, there is no information available on what method is used to actually approve a step, it just displays who approved it and the status.